# How to test refresh and expired token scenarios?

Tags: typescript, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm using the `msal.js` library for authentication against my AAD account. I've got the logic to handle refreshing of tokens implemented, but I'm not sure how best to manually test this.

```js
    try {
      const response = await userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(parameters);
      jwtIdToken = response.idToken.rawIdToken;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
        if (type === LoginType.Redirect) {
          userAgentApplication.acquireTokenRedirect(parameters);
        }

        const response = await userAgentApplication.acquireTokenPopup(parameters);
        jwtIdToken = response.idToken.rawIdToken;
      } else {
        // Error was not related to needing interaction
        throw error;
      }
    }
```

I'm able to verify that the token is being refreshed correctly using the `system` config and setting a token renewal offset to a value larger than the expiration limit.

```
  system: {
    tokenRenewalOffsetSeconds: 60 * 60
  }
```

The only scenario I don't know how to test is when the token can no longer be refreshed, and the user needs to login again after the `InteractionRequiredAuthError` error is thrown. I'm really hoping I don't have to keep a session active for 24 hours then try to refresh the token...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Withdraw user consent from the application - go to the [app portal](https://myapps.microsoft.com), find the JS app and delete it. That will remove your consent from this app and make your refresh tokens invalid. There is a Powershell command for that as well.